# equalizing block of nos

Tags: python, linux, bash, for-loop, awk

I have a text file that contain timing of an experiment as

```
>
0.000
0.010
0.020
0.030
0.040
0.050
>
0.000
0.010
0.020
0.030
>
0.000
0.010
0.020
0.030
0.040
0.050
```

I want to equalize each block by finding out the maximum value of whole input data and then based on the increment on the data(calculated automatically from input) the  individual block should be equalized to maximum value present in the input data and expected output is

```
>
0.000
0.010
0.020
0.030
0.040
0.050
>
0.000
0.010
0.020
0.030
0.040
0.050
>
0.000
0.010
0.020
0.030
0.040
0.050
```

I tried the code as given below but it gives result by repeating the last line of second block as given below which is not same as expected output

```
>
0.000
0.010
0.020
0.030
0.040
0.050
>
0.000
0.010
0.020
0.030
0.030
0.030
>
0.000
0.010
0.020
0.030
0.040
0.050
```

My script

```
awk '$0==">" {
   if (c && c>max)
      max = c
   ++n
   c = 0
   next
}
{
   r[n][++c] = $0
}
END {
   for (i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
      print ">"
      for (j=1; j<=(max>c?max:c); ++j){
         print (r[i][j] == "" ? prev : r[i][j])
         prev=r[i][j]==""?prev:r[i][j]
      }
   }
}' input
```

This code gives the output by repeating the last line values of second block as i am doing some mistake.I hope experts may help overcoming this problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't having the min/max values, the number of blocks and the increment be enough for generating the output from scratch?

Comment: will each block always start with the same number (eg, `0.000`)? will all subsequent numbers be based on the same interval (eg, `0.010`)? would intermediate numbers be mssing (eg, could `0.000`, `0.010`, `0.040` occur)?

Comment: each block start with same nos and end with same nos other two cases mentioned by u can be considered @markp-fuso

Comment: what is the expected **max** size (MBytes) of the input file?

Comment: @it is of gigabyte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions/Understandings:

- all blocks start with the same value (eg, `0.000`)
- all values are incremented by the same amount (eg, `0.010`)
- all blocks are to be expanded to include all values
- net objective is to display the same block `N` times (where `N` is the number of blocks)

One `awk` idea requiring a single pass of the input file:

```
awk '
/^>/          { blkcnt++; next }
!($1 in seen) { seen[$1]; arr[++n]=$1 }
END           { for (i=1;i<=blkcnt;i++) {
                    print ">"
                    for (j=1;j<=n;j++)
                        print arr[j]
                }
              }
' input
```

This generates:

```
>
0.000
0.010
0.020
0.030
0.040
0.050
>
0.000
0.010
0.020
0.030
0.040
0.050
>
0.000
0.010
0.020
0.030
0.040
0.050
```

**NOTE:**

- I'm guessing there's more to OP's real life input file (eg, each line contains additional textual data following the timing value) in which case this solution will not suffice
- if this is the case then OP should update the question with a more representative set of sample data

Comment: An array named `seen[]` as in `!($1 in seen) { seen[$1]; arr[++n]=$1 }` is more commonly, idiomatically used as `!seen[$1]++ { arr[++n]=$1 }`

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't all you need:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    if ( !/>/ && ((max == "") || ($1 > max)) ) {
        max = $1
    }
    if ( (prev == prev+0) && ($1 == $1+0) ) {
        step = $1 - prev
    }
    prev = $1
    next
}
/>/ {
    if ( FNR > 1 ) {
        prt()
    }
}
{
    print
    prev = $1
}
END { prt() }

function prt(   i) {
    for ( i=prev+step; i<=max; i+=step ) {
        printf "%.03f\n", i
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file file
>
0.000
0.010
0.020
0.030
0.040
0.050
>
0.000
0.010
0.020
0.030
0.040
0.050
>
0.000
0.010
0.020
0.030
0.040
0.050
```

then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input/output including cases the above doesn't work for.